# Run a function at forceful termination of the script in Python

Tags: python, logging, termination

I have created a  log and want it to be updated at forceful termination of the python script. This will help in keeping a track of all the forceful terminations. I tried , but `atexit()` runs only on normal termination.

Comment: how is the script being terminated? The keyboard or is it killed by something else?

Comment: Yes, Keyboard will be doing the termination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.

This simple program demonstrates how a function can be run when the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> key combination is pressed to exit.

```
def main():
    while True:
        input('')

def onexit():
    print('on exit')

try:
    main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    onexit()
```

Comment: What about Ctrl + Z?

Comment: That's not termination though is it. It's back grounding the process. See https://superuser.com/questions/476873/what-is-effect-of-ctrl-z-on-a-unix-linux-application/476874

Comment: This will not work for other (non-keyboard) signals for termination (for example, forcefully killing it with `kill -SIGTERM` ). Using the `signal` module and listening to all 'termination' signals is a more encompassing solution.

Comment: Of course but would the atexit function the op is already using not handle that whilst remaining cross platform?